# Translating multiband netCDF to GTiff using gdalwarp and Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp, netcdf

How do I translate (extract) multiband netCDF to individual raster geotiff?

I am new to scripting, so I am hoping you could help me with how I should write my gdal translate script starting from setting my working directory.

---

Instructions that come with the data:

The maps can be transformed to the GTiff format using GDAL as follows, replacing Year, Band_Name and Output_Filename with the parameters of interest:

```
gdalwarp -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -ot Byte -te -180.0000000 -90.0000000 180.0000000 90.0000000 -tr 0.002777777777778 0.002777777777778 -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:xxxYEAR.nc:BandName OutputFilename.tif
```

So far:

```
import os, sys # the standard imports

BaseFolder = r'C:\Users\Dlan\Desktop\netCDF_TIFF' # change this to match your data

for FullPath, dirs, files in os.walk(BaseFolder):
for ThisFile in files:                   # iterate the files
    fN,fE = os.path.splitext(ThisFile)   # separate file name and extension
    if fE.lower() == 'LCCS-2018.nc':
        # this is a netCDF file, though other extensions might exist
        # you will need to provide these details or ascertain them from
        # the input NetCDF file name.

        Year = '2018'
        Band = 'lccs_class'
        OutputName = 'LCCS-2018'


        GDAL_Command = 'gdalwarp -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -ot Byte -te '\
                                     '-180.0000000 -90.0000000 180.0000000 90.0000000 -tr 0.002777777777778 0.002777777777778 '\
                                     '-t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:{}YEAR.nc:{} {}.tif'.format( Year, Band, os.path.join(FullPath,OutputName))
        os.system(GDAL_Command) # run the command
```

There are some other instructions:

The maps can be transformed to the GTiff format using GDAL as follows, replacing Year, Band_Name and Output_Filename with the parameters of interest:

with Year the year : 2016, 2017 or 2018; and BandName one of the following: lccs_class; processed_flag; current_pixel_state; observation_count; change_count.

Format:
    `gdalwarp -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -ot Byte -te -180.0000000 -90.0000000 180.0000000 90.0000000 -tr 0.002777777777778 0.002777777777778 -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:XXX-YEAR.nc:BandName OutputFilename.tif`

Example code: 
`gdalwarp -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -ot Byte -te -180.0000000 -90.0000000 180.0000000 90.0000000 -tr 0.002777777777778 0.002777777777778 -t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:LCCS-2018.nc:lccs_class LCCS-2018.tif`

Comment: You are talking about two different platforms: ArcGIS and GDAL, which one is it? If you're trying to iterate with arcpy.da.walk and then launch GDAL_Translate you will have to ensure that GDAL_Translate executes from a CMD window (anything other than *'gdal_translate' is not recognized as an internal or external command* should be enough). Do you have *any* code to work from? We would need this to cater an answer to your level of experience, if you have code, no matter how bad or sloppy it is, please edit it into your question.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks so much for your reply. Actually, I don't have any script to start from. What I have is the instructions that come with the data, as edited above. thank you

Comment: Oh, I see. When you open a CMD window and type in gdalwarp is it recognized by the CMD processor? With no options specified it should print a 'usage' message. If not you will have to open a GDAL shell window, OSGeo4W should work, from here you can drag and drop your python file with arcpy commands and theoretically it should work, I can help with a basic framework if you can ensure the gdalwarp command is recognized.

Comment: It says --- 'gdalwarp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.--- I'm sorry, I don't really know what to do. Could you please explain a bit more about OSGeo4W? thank you

Comment: OSGeo4W is a GDAL installer, if you've installed your GDAL core components it places a shell on your desktop, if you've installed from GISInternals you will need to make your own shell, use the existing "C:\Program Files\GDAL\GDALShell.bat" or insert your GDAL path into your environment path, for example SET PATH="C:\your\path\to\GDAL";%path% - the semicolon and percents are crucial here, also no spaces either side of the equals.

Comment: I've edited your question so that it has become about using Python with gdalwarp.  I've done that to retrofit it to the answer and make a focused Q&A.  If you also seek an ArcPy solution then you just need to ask that in a separate question.

Comment: PolyGeo, thanks so much. My apologies for any inconvenience as I am new to this support system and to the topic I am working on. ty

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with a simple [walk](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) or [listdir](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_listdir.htm):

```
import os, sys # the standard imports

BaseFolder = r'c:\your\folder\with\data' # change this to match your data

for FullPath, dirs, files in os.walk(BaseFolder):
    for ThisFile in files:                   # iterate the files
        fN,fE = os.path.splitext(ThisFile)   # separate file name and extension
        if fE.lower() == '.nc':
            # this is a netCDF file, though other extensions might exist
            # you will need to provide these details or ascertain them from
            # the input NetCDF file name.
            Year = 'XXXX'
            Band = 'bandName'
            OutputName = 'OutputName.tif'

            GDAL_Command = 'gdalwarp -of Gtiff -co COMPRESS=LZW -co TILED=YES -ot Byte -te '\
                                         '-180.0000000 -90.0000000 180.0000000 90.0000000 -tr 0.002777777777778 0.002777777777778 '\
                                         '-t_srs EPSG:4326 NETCDF:{}YEAR.nc:{} {}.tif'.format( Year, Band, os.path.join(FullPath,OutputName))
            os.system(GDAL_Command) # run the command
```

Hopefully you can derive your output name from your input, I don't have enough information to decide that but this will help loop through the folders and run the command when you have decided what the command should contain. Note the '\ on the end of each line is a continuation character to split the sting onto multiple lines for readability.

Before you can start with the coding portion of this you need to have your warp command recognized. If you don't have OSGeo4W shell there is a shell batch in your GDAL install folder or you could navigate to your GDAL\bin folder with a command like `CD /D "C:\Program Files\GDAL"` where the gdalwarp executable resides.

Comment: I have installed OSGeo4W. Did you mean to say that I shall copy the script above to the OSGeo4W shell and change the necessary strings? thank you

Comment: No, the OSGeo shell simply has the right paths to call (find) GDALWarp. You need to copy the text into a notepad (notepad++ or pywin is better) document then save as file type .py (make sure it isn't .py.txt as Windows will do if you have 'hide extensions for known types' turned on) then drag from Windows explorer (or dOpus) into the command window and press enter to execute the python code. Ideally part of the output file name should be a substring of the input file name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663171/how-do-i-get-a-substring-of-a-string-in-python

Comment: C:\>"C:\Users\Dlan\Desktop\netCDF_TIFF\test1.py"
  File "C:\Users\Dlan\Desktop\netCDF_TIFF\test1.py", line 2
    >>> import os, sys # the standard imports
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: That is very odd, can you post the code you have so far in your question. I think it might have something to do with the imports being on line 2 rather than the first line.. python can be fussy about the first line and what it should contain.

Comment: How can I post the script? ty

Comment: Edit it into your question with copy/paste. As a new user you are only able to edit your own questions, please use the {} button to format your code.

Comment: I have posted the script above.. I am also wondering whether NETCDF:{}YEAR at the bottom is the right one because YEAR is written, but Band and OutputName are not written. thank you

Comment: The curly braces {} are placeholders in the string for the .format() function, when the code is run the values of the variables are inserted. The script looks fine but do you have an empty first line?

Comment: No, I don't have an empty first line. I created the script in ArcMap so it has >>> in the first line and ... for the succeeding lines (both for lines with script and empty). I think the data is for 2018 only because I downloaded only 2018, but it has several bands as mentioned above. I am interested in band "lccs_class". What if I remove the Year, Band and OutputName, and just follow the suggested example code by filling in the necessary info. In this case, what should I do to ".format( Year, Band, os.path.join(FullPath,OutputName))
            os.system(GDAL_Command) # run the command "?

Comment: That could work but you would be overwriting your output on each iteration; there shouldn't be a >>> unless you're typing this into an IDE python window which may have issues with the comment on the same line. The os.walk traverses the folder tree, passing the files and folders encountered, if you don't want to do that you can remove the walk and unindent the block, in which case the need for python is negated as you could easily run this in a batch file, changing the input/output names as needed.